# Truncated image when creating textures from png

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, textures

I am trying to create a texture from a png using the following code:

```
...
var texture = gl.createTexture();
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    gl.activeTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}
img.src = "/path/to/image.png"
```

My problem is that WebGL complains about "bad image data". Debugging in firebug shows me that the image is truncated, the png file downloaded is only part of the original file - the top half. Firefox also complains that "image is corrupt or truncated". The original file is around 1.8 MB (2048x1024). What could be the problem and how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible causes for your problem but there a re few things you can do to try and narrow it down.

Try resizing your image to 2048x2048 and 1024x1024 in case the problem is based on the fact that you have a non-square texture.

Also try saving your texture as a .jpg and trying to load.  Also open up your png in your image editor of choice and try saving in a few different png [types](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html#png.ch08.div.5) available (pallete based, grayscale, RGB, RGB with transparency, RGBA etc) to see if it will load.

Comment: I have already tried resizing without success. Will try the other two to see the result. They won't solve my problem however as the pngs are given to me and I can't change them. Could you mention a few of the causes you say are possible? I don't have a clue.